# How to send a POST request from RestSharp on android to a WebAPI server

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, restsharp

I have an android app that needs to make a call to a asp.net core web api server.

I am using RestSharp to make the request.

Here is the code generating the request:

```
public LoginResponse SignInWithGoogle(string token)
        {
            //Api request for token
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("login/google", Method.POST);

            request.AddJsonBody(new { Token = token });
            //request.AddParameter("token", token, ParameterType.GetOrPost);

            var response = restClient.Execute<LoginResponse>(request);

            if (response.ErrorException != null)
            {
                throw new Exception("The APi request failed. See inner exception for more details", response.ErrorException);
            }

            AuthenticationToken = response.Data.token;
            restClient.Authenticator = authenticator;

            return response.Data;
        }
```

Here is the web api code:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("google")]
public IActionResult GoogleLogin([FromBody] GoogleLoginDto data)
{
    GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload payload;
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    SigningCredentials creds = new SigningCredentials(Global.symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    //Try to validate the Google token.
    try
    {
        payload = GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(data.Token).Result;                
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }
...
}
```

`GoogleLoginDto` contains one property `Token` that is public.

The problem is that I get a 404. It seems to me that the JSON in the request is not being serialized to `GoogleLoginDto` but I can't find out why... I'm guessing because the API can't find the `data` field and so thinks i'm asking for a route that doesn't exist...

I also tried doing `request.AddParameter("token", token, ParameterType.GetOrPost);` as you can see, but I get an exception saying that `Content-Type` can't be null.

I thought about adding the `Content-Type` header but that seems ridiculous because RestSharp is supposed to determine that automatically...

Can anyone see anything I'm missing here? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you're using the correct url?

Comment: You say it works from Postman, so have you compared the requests using Fiddler or something? It should be quite straightforward to see.

Answer (score 0):

The API is unable to map the provided URL to a controller action. That is what it is 404 Not Found. Nothing to do with the data. It is the URL.

Given that the desired URL is `login/google`, ensure that the target controller has the proper routes defined that would allow the request to be mapped to the correct actions.

```
[Route("login")] // Route prefix
public class LoginController : Controller {    
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("google")] // Matches POST login/google
    public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLogin([FromBody] GoogleLoginDto data) {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload payload;
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(Global.symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);        
            //Try to validate the Google token.
            try {
                payload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(data.Token);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }    
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have. The problem is with the request. It works fine from postman.